# Read user stream,does it needs Facebook review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am reading and reading, and the `Facebook api`, just makes it hard to understand what you can and can't do.

So , if you get the access token for streaming permission :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=xxxx&code=&scope=email,read_stream
```

You get a token (without Facebook to ask you for permissions...) .

than you get error for `"extended permission needed"` when you try to get the user feed:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?accesstoken=
```

If you read on `Facebook` , they say that your app needs a review to get these permissions.
If you read in `google`, you can see that you can't get permissions from Facebook for this, because you can "replicate" their app .

But, you can see some people that do gets the a user feed, and also , there is a way to get the permission for the user feed, as i just showed.

So , what is going on here ? do you need a permission to get a user feed ?  if you do need, why do they write that you will not get it anyway, unless "your app is going to replicate Facebook in a platform that still not have Facebook" .

We just can't understand if and how you can get a user feed .

Comment: After the recent changes to FB API and terms, various permissions you request have to go through review and they will allow only when they find it relevant based on use of any specific permission in your app. If you were using an older app there won't be any such problem till v1.0 API is working. So you will have to get the permission reviewed and approved by providing proper reasoning.

Comment: _“if you do need, why do they write that you will not get it anyway, unless […]”_ – because you will be able to get it, if your app satisfies the “unless” part …

Answer (score 0):

It's all outlined and visible in the docs. Have a look here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

For every permission other than

- public_profile
- user_friends
- email

you'll need to get your app reviewed.

Comment: This is still not makes anything clear. First, Facebook says clearly, that if your app is replicate Facebook in a platform that dont have Facebook than ,only than, you can get user stream . Since this is not the case to ANY one (iOS,Android,web), so no one can get that stream . Yet, Facebook gives more than 3 pages to explain how you get that permission, and what exactly to do . (even if its not relevant to almost anybody in the world)

Comment: The general process is that if you request extended permissions, then you need to pass the review process. There are certain permissions (and `read_stream` is such a permission) which has additional regulations. I don't think that this is clearly documented in one place. But still, the process is as outlined. If you don't have a v1.0 app, then you don't have a chance to surpass this,